# Python - unpack using struct in Django

Tags: python, c, django, struct

I'm getting a C-structure as a JSON field in Django requests, and need to parse it,

The structure is :

```
typedef struct __attribute__((packed)) _data_t
{
    unsigned long long      timestamp;
    unsigned int            value;
} data_t;
```

edit: I'm uploading this via libcurl like so:

```
data_t data;
...
curl_formadd(&formpost,
        &lastptr,
        CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "data",
        CURLFORM_COPYCONTENTS, &data,
        CURLFORM_CONTENTSLENGTH, size,
        CURLFORM_END);
```

Now, the way I'm trying to unpack this data is using python struct.unpack, like so:

`packet = unpack('>QI', pkt)`

However, I keep getting `error: unpack requires a string argument of length 12`

This is expected had the size of `pkt` not been 12

however,

`len(pkt)` prints `12`

`pkt` prints `7l��}�`

`repr(pkt)` prints `u'7l\x11\ufffd\ufffd}\x00\x00\ufffd\r\x00\x00'`

I'm suspecting encoding issues (though I absolutely do not need any kind of encoding).

Any ways to get this to work?

Comment: How do you pack the struct?

Comment: if you mean in C, I have described it in the `typedef`, in python I assume `>QI` means no padding.

Comment: What does the string look like in the HTTP request? Are you sure the input is correct, including any encoding settings? You're getting a 12-character Unicode string which doesn't correspond to a 12-byte string in any of the immediately obvious encodings (UTF8, latin-1).

Comment: I'm not really including any encoded strings, See [edit] for how I'm posting the data, I get the unicode/whatever encoded string in Django.

Answer (score 1):

You have a unicode string of length 12 (unicode characters). struct needs a binary string of 12 bytes length.

You started with a binary string in your C code, so you need to work out how it has been decoded to unicode, so that you can reverse the operation, or work out how to get the original binary string from django.

Also you might want to define your C structure in terms of fixed size types ( uint64_t etc) so that you don't have problems on different platforms.